# Excell removing least two scores from a list. The list may have #N/A in it

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to remove the least two scores from a list and take the average of the remaining 4. The list may have  #N/A 
For example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for telling us.  Do you have a question? If so what did you try and what didn't work?

Comment: To do what with it; sum, average,...?

Comment: I want to be able to add the columns (B2 through G2) and remove the lowest two scores and then divide by 4 to get an average. I know how to do this with Roll 2 but in Roll 3 using the following  there is an #N/A and which I have issues

Comment: If you remove the lowest 2 would you not have 5.  so to get the average would it not be divided by 5 instead of 4?

Comment: do we count the `#N/A` as a low score to be one of the two dissmissed?  Or in row three we would only capture and average the three 4s?

Comment: I want to be able to add the columns (B2 through G2) and remove the lowest two scores and then divide by 4 to get an average. I know how to do this with Roll 2 but in Roll 3 using the following  formula places #N/A in A3
=SUM(SUM(B2:G2)-SMALL(B2:G2,1)-SMALL(B2:G2,2))/4
I tried substituting B2:G2 with IFERROR(B1,0)+IFERROR(B2,0) ..... but get #NUM!

Comment: See my edits below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This array formula will average scores that are not the two lowest or errors:

```
=AVERAGE(LARGE(IFERROR(B2:G2,-1E+99),ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & MIN(COUNT(B2:G2),4)))))
```

being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

So put the formula in A2.  Hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter, then copy/drag down.

This will ignore the N/As completely, so if there are 3 N/As it will average only the three numbers remaining.

[image: ![enter image description here]

---

Edit:

If you do not want to ignore the N/As but treat them as 0 then use this:

```
=AVERAGE(LARGE(IFERROR(B2:G2,0),ROW(INDIRECT("1:4" ))))
```

Again it is an array formula so the above rules apply to how it needs to be entered.

This will treat N/A's as 0 and include them if there are more than two in the average.

[image]

Comment: Scott - That worked, Thnx a lot!!!
Marty

Comment: @KTMarty please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.